# Google Analytics For Android: No tracking information displayed

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm having a terrible time getting any information to show in the Google Analytics console. Per other StackOverflow questions, here is everything I've tried.

1. Waited 48 hours for stats to show up
2. Opened another GA account and waited 48 hours
3. Verified the information is being sent to Google using "setDebug" (see printout below)
4. Ran the GA example app and waiting 48 hours
5. Worked through everything on the [the following link](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/)
6. Switched to using EasyTracker code
7. Ran these tests from three different phones
8. Ran these tests on local internet and mobile data
9. Made sure the Google Analytics date range is set correctly
10. Checked that the "hosts" file on the phone doesn't block GA http requests silently

If it is useful, my tracking ID is in the format UA-xxxxxxxx-1, many examples do not have eight numbers in the middle.

What else could be the problem here? I've compiled as many things as I can, I just can't seem to get any data to show up in GA despite the following....

```
12-02 09:46:26.020: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): Host: www.google-analytics.com
12-02 09:46:26.020: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JOP40D)
12-02 09:46:26.020: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=1427846719&utmt=event&utme=5(**)(0)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=320x494&utmul=en-US&utmac=UA-36617299-1&utmcc=__utma%3D1.2145684843.1354301001.1354462815.1354463165.7%3B&utmht=1354463165997&utmqt=20025 HTTP/1.1
12-02 09:46:26.020: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): Scheduled next dispatch
12-02 09:46:26.020: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): Sending 1 hits to dispatcher
12-02 09:46:26.280: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): HTTP Response Code: 200
12-02 09:46:46.041: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): Called dispatch
12-02 09:46:46.041: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(27347): ...but there was nothing to dispatch
```

Comment: feeling sorry after reading your question :(

Comment: Looks like you have tried a lot, I don't have any clue to why it is not working but I can tell you that the tracking ID format **is valid**, I have the same and it works very well. I hope that you find the solution :/

Comment: @HarshaMV Yes. If you select "website" instead of app, then things worked. I've since moved to Flurry though. Google hasn't let me in the version 2.0 beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth checking that you are using the right SDK with the right property setting in Google Analytics.

If you are using SDK 2.0 you need to select "app".
If you are not but are using a legacy version then you would need to select "website" and then put in a dummy web address. It wont use the dummy address but will instead accept the data from the SDK.

Please let me know if this helps or if you need me to be more specific.

Comment: He Dennis. I created a new GA account as a website instead of an app, and everything is showing up now. Can you explain a little bit more about this? At this time, when I create an account, Google says nothing about SDK 2.0 being needed, where to get it, or anything along these lines. As I'm adding this code to an Android app, I'd prefer to view the data in an app centric way.

Comment: Hi Justin. The new SDK and the new interface were designed specifically for apps whereas the old one is basically mimicking the calls that a website would be calling. The new interface will also be receiving and displaying information that doesn't exist on webpages (like app version) and I guess that google simply decided that making and app specific version makes sense. For me this is true as some of the things I was calling via Custom Variables (eg app version) are now collected automatically and displayed in a way that i really like and find useful.

Comment: Hi Dennis. My problem isn't that there have been improvements in app analytics. That is great. The problem I've having is that "At this time, when I create an account, Google says nothing about SDK 2.0 being needed, where to get it, or anything along these lines." Since Google isn't alerting users that they need a different SDK then the one they are currently shipping, do you have any of this information? Where did you find it?

Comment: Here is the SDK guide for Andoid: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/ and here is the guide for IOS: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/. It includes a migration guide if you want to change from a pre-existing SDK implementation.

Comment: @DennisBunchofgrapesJordan i am facing the same problem. I am using the v2 and have selected as APP in the Service. Yet i dont see any changes in the activity - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302460/android-google-analytics-tracking

Comment: This is true for v3 of the SDK as well - using a 'website' account won't work, the stats won't show up for it. +1 for solving my issue.