# Android Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have set up Google Analytics v2 beta on a test project as bellow

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;

        // Set Context to Google Analytics
        EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);

        EasyTracker.getInstance();
        Tracker myTracker = EasyTracker.getTracker();
        myTracker.sendView("harsha");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

analytics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA&#8211;37418075&#8211;1</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
    <!-- The screen names that will appear in your reporting -->
    <string name="com.m7.google_analytics_v2.BaseActivity">Home</string>

</resources>
```

I have been trying to send the tracking to Google Analytics Server but not able to find any hits or activity of any kind. Does it take time for it to reflect ?

I find this in the Log Cat

```
01-13 15:16:52.360: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:52.360: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
01-13 15:16:52.440: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:52.440: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
01-13 15:16:53.825: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:53.825: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
01-13 15:16:53.905: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:53.905: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
01-13 15:16:57.840: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:57.840: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
01-13 15:16:57.945: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
01-13 15:16:57.945: I/GAV2(23176): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't look good:

```
 <string name="ga_trackingId">UA&#8211;37418075&#8211;1</string>
```

`&#8211;` (–) is `&ndash`; which is a different character from the ASCII - (-) (`&#45`).  I'm pretty sure GA just expects ASCII in the tracking Id.

Unless that was just inserted when pasting into stack overflow.

Comment: no i had inserted that upon eclipses suggestion for the default one. cant we just use - instead of the ASCII code ?

Comment: Replace "-" with an "en dash" character (–, &#8211;) ?

Comment: When i see the log cat.. its tries to keep sending analytics very often. any idea how to slow it down ?

Comment: @HarshaMV Not sure .. try starting a new SO question

Comment: put this to stop warnings from Eclipse: <resources
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

Answer (score 1):

Try create a new profile on Google Analytics under Admin and also set it as an App, it will provide you a new tracking number.

I had similar problem, for some reasons Google Analytics v2 didnt not work on my old Google Analytics project, so i created new project and a new profile, same code started reporting data after 24-36 hours. But you can also check using real time data if its hitting Google analytics server or not.

Comment: its a new app itself. have i set up the tracking in a right way ?

Comment: are you able to see anything on real time Analytics with-in 30 seconds to a minute of an user activity from device.

Comment: It usually takes around 24 to 36 hours to show all details, if its showing a spike in real time analytics, you are good.

Comment: i have waited for two days now and have been testing the demo app. i dont see any hits. how to see real time data in the app version of ga ?

Comment: On website, Under Home : its first things on left. I havent tried mobile app for GA